# Program output isn't displaying correctly?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program isn't printing correctly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761204/program-isnt-printing-correctly)

#include

## include// needed for toupper function

## include// needed to exit file

//Eric Brooks
//Chapter 10 Tax Program
//04/19/2011

int main()
{
    FILE*tax;// declare that tax is a file

```
int holdScreen, taxpayerId, grossIncome, taxExemptions;
char fillingStatus;
float taxableIncome,taxRate,taxAmount;
tax = fopen("tax.txt","r");// open tax for reading
//tax = fopen("txttemp.txt.txt","r");// open tax for reading
if (tax == NULL)
   {
        printf("Failed to open file. \n");
        scanf("%d",&holdScreen);
        exit(1);
   }
printf("\n\t\t\t\tTax Table");
printf("\n\n Taxpayer ID  \t Taxable Income  \tTax Rate  \tTax Amount");// print heading for output
printf("\n -----------  \t --------------  \t--------  \t----------");// print heading for output





while(fscanf(tax,"\n%d %c %d %d ",&taxpayerId, &fillingStatus, &grossIncome, &taxExemptions) != EOF)
{    


                    fillingStatus = toupper(fillingStatus);

                    if ( fillingStatus == 'S')
                    {
                        taxableIncome = grossIncome - 3000 - 1000 * taxExemptions;

                    }
                    else if ( fillingStatus == 'M')
                    {
                        taxableIncome = grossIncome - 3000 - 1000 * taxExemptions;

                    }   
                    else if ( fillingStatus == 'J')
                    {
                        taxableIncome = grossIncome - 6000 - 1000 * taxExemptions;

                    }

                    if (taxableIncome < 0)
                    {
                        taxableIncome = 0;
                    }


                    if ( fillingStatus == 'S')
                    {
                            if (taxableIncome < 5000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.15;
                            }
                            if (taxableIncome  > 20000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.31;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.22;
                            }
                    }     
                    else if ( fillingStatus == 'M')
                    {
                            if (taxableIncome < 10000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.15;

                            }   
                            if (taxableIncome > 40000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.31;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.22;
                            }
                    }
                    else if ( fillingStatus == 'J')
                    {
                            if (taxableIncome < 7000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.17;
                            }
                            if (taxableIncome > 25000)
                            {    
                                taxRate = 0.33;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.24;
                            } 
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                            printf("\n %d     **** Invalid filling status ****",taxpayerId);
                            continue;
                    }

                    if (taxExemptions > 12  || taxExemptions < 0) 
                    {
                        printf("\n %d     **** Invalid number of exemptions ****", taxpayerId);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        taxAmount = taxableIncome * taxRate;
                        printf("\n %d %15.2f  %15.2f  %18.2f",taxpayerId,taxableIncome,taxRate,taxAmount);
                    }  





}

fclose(tax);// close file tax
scanf("%d",&holdScreen);
return 0;
```

}

Output is supposed to look like this but its not working properly. I believe it hasn't something to do with the if statement and the 's' || 'S' 'm' || 'M' || 'j' || 'J'.

```
                          Tax Table

Taxpayer ID    Taxable Income    Tax Rate        Tax Amount
-----------    --------------    --------        ----------

111111111           4000.00        0.15            600.00
222222222          36500.00        0.22           8030.00
333333333          19152.00        0.24           4596.48
444444444    **** Invalid filing status ****
555555555          67000.00        0.31          20770.00
666666666          53197.00        0.33          17555.01
777777777          19000.00        0.22           4180.00
888888888    **** Invalid number of exemptions ****
999999999          46308.00        0.33          15281.64
101010101          91602.00        0.31          28396.62
121212121           9525.00        0.15           1428.75
131313131              0.00        0.17              0.00
```