# Program isn't printing correctly

Tags: c++

I believe my program is still going through the if statements after it is declared invalid. It should print invalid filling status or invalid exemption status on the same line with the id. Buts its printing the valid statement above the the id and still displaying the taxableIncome and taxRate and TaxAmount.
    while(fscanf(tax,"\n%d %c %d %d ",&taxpayerId, &fillingStatus, &grossIncome, &taxExemptions) != EOF)
    {

```
                    fillingStatus = toupper(fillingStatus);

                    if ( fillingStatus == 'S')
                    {
                        taxableIncome = grossIncome - 3000 - 1000 * taxExemptions;

                    }
                    else if ( fillingStatus == 'M')
                    {
                        taxableIncome = grossIncome - 3000 - 1000 * taxExemptions;

                    }   
                    else if ( fillingStatus == 'J')
                    {
                        taxableIncome = grossIncome - 6000 - 1000 * taxExemptions;

                    }

                    if (taxableIncome < 0)
                    {
                        taxableIncome = 0;
                    }


                    if ( fillingStatus == 'S')
                    {
                            if (taxableIncome < 5000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.15;
                            }
                            if (taxableIncome  > 20000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.31;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.22;
                            }
                    }     
                    else if ( fillingStatus == 'M')
                    {
                            if (taxableIncome < 10000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.15;

                            }   
                            if (taxableIncome > 40000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.31;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.22;
                            }
                    }
                    else if ( fillingStatus == 'J')
                    {
                            if (taxableIncome < 7000)
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.17;
                            }
                            if (taxableIncome > 25000)
                            {    
                                taxRate = 0.33;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                taxRate = 0.24;
                            } 
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                            printf("\n %d     **** Invalid filling status ****",taxpayerId);
                            continue;
                    }

                    if (taxExemptions > 12  || taxExemptions < 0) 
                    {
                        printf("\n %d     **** Invalid number of exemptions ****", taxpayerId);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        taxAmount = taxableIncome * taxRate;
                        printf("\n %d %15.2f  %15.2f  %18.2f",taxpayerId,taxableIncome,taxRate,taxAmount);
                    }
```

Output is suppose to look like this:

> ```
> Taxpayer ID    Taxable Income    Tax Rate        Tax Amount
> -----------    --------------    --------        ----------
>
> 111111111           4000.00        0.15            600.00
> 222222222          36500.00        0.22           8030.00
> 333333333          19152.00        0.24           4596.48
> 444444444    **** Invalid filing status ****
> 555555555          67000.00        0.31          20770.00
> 666666666          53197.00        0.33          17555.01
> 777777777          19000.00        0.22           4180.00
> 888888888    **** Invalid number of exemptions ****
> 999999999          46308.00        0.33          15281.64
> 101010101          91602.00        0.31          28396.62
> 121212121           9525.00        0.15           1428.75
> 131313131              0.00        0.17              0.00
> ```

My out put look like this:

> Taxpayer ID    Taxable Income
>   Tax Rate        Tax Amount
>       -----------    --------------    --------        ----------
>
> ```
> 111111111           4000.00        0.22            880.00
> 222222222          36500.00        0.31          11315.00
> 333333333          19152.00        0.24           4596.48
> 444444444          **** Invalid filing status ****           
> 555555555          67000.00        0.31          20770.00
> 666666666          53197.00        0.24          12767.28
> 777777777          **** Invalid number of exemptions ****        
> 888888888           3543.00        0.22
> 999999999          46308.00        0.24            779.46
> 101010101          91602.00        0.22          11113.92
> 121212121           9525.00        0.31           2952.75
> 131313131              0.00        0.24              0.00
> ```

Comment: This isn't C#, this looks like C or C++.

Comment: What's the actual output you're getting? Also, you could call tolower() against your input so you didn't have to make boolean operations between the two cases..

Comment: You really should use return statements. Whenever something is invalid, print out and exit the program / function call. The way you are doing it, it is just printing stuff and continuing to the next stage.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Can you do the following: reduce it to the minimum required to demonstrate your problem, and more carefully spell out what you're trying to achieve and what it is doing wrong? Also, see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for some more advice on how to ask the question for maximum response.

Comment: I don't see where your "valid" filing status or "id" is printing. You need to provide some more information.

Comment: Why did you post this again, instead of just adding an additional tag?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd like to request that you ask a new question for your printing issue. That helps keep this question from getting cluttered up with additional questions and answers. Please try to make a shorter example of what you're having trouble with (questions with shorter code samples tend to get better answers). – Greg Hewgill 51 mins ago                                                                  Because I was asked to.

Comment: If you read the last comment on program output isn't displaying correctly??? I was asked to ask a new question.

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761204/program-isnt-printing-correctly

Comment: Yes it is but Greg Hewgill asked me to post a new question up in the first comment box so I did.

Comment: @Eric, you've re-edited your post and wiped out the edits i had done for you earlier. Now your code segment is both not complete and is hard to read. People cannot answer you accurately if your code sample is not good.

Answer (score 4):

```
fillingStatus == 's' || 'S'
```

The above condition does not do what you appear to think it does. Try:

```
fillingStatus == 's' || fillingStatus == 'S'
```

The reason is that the `==` operator only compares one pair of values at a time. So your expression reads something like:

> if (fillingStatus is 's') or ('S' is nonzero)

which is always true (since `'S'` is always nonzero). The corrected expression reads like:

> if (fillingStatus is 's') or (fillingStatus is 'S')

It might be worth noting that some other languages have less verbose ways of expressing this condition than the above C++ code. For example, in Python you can write:

```
if fillingStatus in ('s', 'S'):
```

which tests `fillingStatus` for either `'s'` or `'S'`.

Comment: You could also do this and skip the second comparison all together:

's' == tolower(fillingStatus)

Comment: @BrMcMullin: Yes, but that doesn't help explain *why* the original code is incorrect.

Comment: You are correct thanks man. Also the invalid filling status and invalid exemption status is suppose to print on the line with the invalid entry but it prints out before the line is there away to fix that?

Comment: I changed the coding to : if ( fillingStatus == 's' || fillingStatus == 'S') and I am able to get the output printed correctly except the invalid statement. I am still new to coding and I am not sure exactly what to try to fix the invalid statement to print with the id instead of above the id.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: You are totally correct, but you had already done a great job at explaining why it failed so I thought I'd share an alternate way to test for the same condition that didn't require as many tests. Didn't mean to distract from your answer in any way.

Comment: I believe the toupper would work but I would most likely have to do:   fillingStatus = toupper(fillingStatus); && fillingStatus = tolower(fillingStatus); do to the fact that the data entry is either upper of lower case.

Comment: @Eric: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd like to request that you ask a *new* question for your printing issue. That helps keep this question from getting cluttered up with additional questions and answers. Please try to make a shorter example of what you're having trouble with (questions with shorter code samples tend to get better answers).

Answer (score 2):

You might consider doing the following after the scanf:

```
fillingStatus = toupper(fillingStatus);
```

Then only test for the uppercase characters:

```
fillingStatus == 'S'
```

You need to fix your 'ifs' as suggested and print output like the following. It won't be quite right until you've fixed the 'ifs', though.

```
if (taxExemptions > 12  || taxExemptions < 0) {
    printf("\n %d \t**** Invalid exemptions status ****", taxpayerId);
} else {
    taxAmount = taxableIncome * taxRate;
    printf("\n %d \t %.2f \t\t %.2f \t %15.2f",taxpayerId,taxableIncome,taxRate,taxAmount);
}
```

The more I look at this code, the more I'm confused too. What should the tax rate be for someone with taxableIncome of 1 and fillingStatus == 'S'. I think it's going to be 0.31, since it's less than 20000. Probably not what you're going for. I think you're missing some 'else if' statments.

Comment: Filling status for s is suppose to be less than 5000 = 15% 5000 to 20000 = 22% more than 20000 = 31%. Thanks for the help you were correct on the if else statement coding that you posted that fixed my error. The only problem I have now is the tax rate doesn't go with the correct filling status and taxable income.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 else
    {       
        printf("\n**** Invalid filling status ****");
    }

    if (taxExemptions > 12  || taxExemptions < 0)
    {       
        printf("\n**** Invalid exemptions status ****");
    }
```

to

```
else
    {       
        printf("\n**** Invalid filling status ****");  
        continue;
    }

    if (taxExemptions > 12  || taxExemptions < 0)
    {       
        printf("\n**** Invalid exemptions status ****");
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
based on the updated question, it is clear that the problem lies not with the horrendous `if` statements, but with the input data - you are picking the wrong record as having invalid number of exemptions. This means two things:

- you should have posted this earlier and saved people a lot of time looking in the wrong place
- you need to show the data that you are consuming if you want an opinion on why you are flagging the wrong record.

I've deleted my original answer. Next time please post **ALL** the relevant details.

Comment: We haven't gone over else if in class this is just my knowledge of reading through material. Can you post an example of how it should look like?

Comment: @Eric, I added more to my answer.

Comment: Sorry but this does work. Thanks.                                                                                                                                      else
                        {   
                                printf("\n %d     **** Invalid filling status ****",taxpayerId);
                                continue;
                        }
                        
                        if (taxExemptions > 12  || taxExemptions < 0) 
                        {
                            printf("\n %d     **** Invalid number of exemptions ****", taxpayerId);

Comment: Pavan said to just add continue; That doesn't change anything. I needed to move the printf statement into the else if statement for it to work correctly as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use commas inside numbers in C++.  The comma is the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

So instead of 7,000 write 7000.

```
if(taxable_income>7,000)
{
   x;
}
```

Would never execute x;

Comment: Thanks I knew this I was just being stupid but thanks for pointing this out